# JavaFX - add border radius to HTMLEditor

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add a `-fx-border-radius` to my `HTMLEditor` object, which unfortunatly is not working.

How can I achieve this? I already tried adding the `HTMLEditor` to a style altered `Pane` which also didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define also the border color and width as:

```
.html-editor {
-fx-border-color: blue;
-fx-border-width: 2;
-fx-border-radius: 1;
}
```